# Animating width and height in rotating cube

Tags: css

I have a rotating cube rotating with this CSS3 animation:

```
@-webkit-keyframes rotating {
    from { -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg); }
    to { -webkit-transform: rotateX(360deg) rotateY(360deg); }
}

.animate {
    -webkit-animation: rotating 4s infinite linear; 
}
```

I want the cube to grow and shrink while rotating, so I tried adding `width` and `height` to the rule:

```
@-webkit-keyframes rotating {
    from { -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
            width: 0; height: 0; }
    to { -webkit-transform: rotateX(360deg) rotateY(360deg);
            width: 300px; height: 300px;}
}
```

But that doesn't give what I expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `scale(0,0)` to `scale(1,1)` with your animation (try to use `scale2D()` if it doesn't work). Also set width and height for element before using scale

```
.element{
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotating {
    from { 
      -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) scale(0, 0);  
    }
    to { 
      -webkit-transform: rotateX(360deg) rotateY(360deg) scale(1, 1);       
    }
}
```